# How to upload multiple images from gallary to recyclerview using mvvm in android

Tags: android

I have completed my task to upload multiple images from gallery to recyclerview and show them but i have done it without mvvm

now i want to do it with mvvm so kinldy help me if anyone knows how to do it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So just use a ViewModel without your List. And your ViewModel shold call some Provider where you get information from database or interner.